# pass div height and width to image

Tags: javascript, jquery

i m just trying to add div in document body but not able to do image size default as div  have
try to fit image in div without give height and width,its depend on div only..
so what can i do..

**HTML**

```
 <div id="placehere" style="height: 250px; width: 300px; 
      overflow:hidden;position:absolute">
```

**Javascript**

```
window.onload=function(){
   var elem = document.createElement("img");
   elem.setAttribute("src", "images/slider-1.jpg");
   elem.setAttribute("height", "");
   elem.setAttribute("width", "");
   elem.setAttribute("alt", "");
   document.getElementById("placehere").appendChild(elem);
}
```

Comment: Please tidy/format your code better

Comment: my simple question is how to set image in div using div heigth width

Comment: what can i do pass div height and width

Comment: I know your question, i was just saying you needed to tidy your code

Comment: okk...next time i will do properly,tell me proper solution for it plz

Comment: I don't. I still can't understand the question...

Comment: @user3851652 There are already two answers to your question...

Comment: thanks both r working

Comment: next time coding will be tidy/

Comment: if i just want to do with attribute concept then whats the code is used

Comment: attribute coding not working ............its not show the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BenM already provide good answer using css but if you want using jquery then you can try this:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dv=$('#placehere');
    var img=$('<img/>',{ width:dv.width()+'px',height:dv.height()+'px',src:"images/slider-1.jpg"});
    dv.append(img);
  });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shE58/17/)

Comment: if i just want to do with attribute concept then what will i do

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use CSS for that? There really is no need to use JS to transfer the sizes of the containing `<div>` to the `<img>`:

The following CSS definitions should achieve what you need:

```
#placehere img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/227q8/)

Comment: if i want to do with attribute concept ...its passible, i am not want to use css then??

Comment: Much better than my javaScript.
I was considering to post a question and I found the answer here.
Thank You @BenM +1